# Cantor Set and Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f,g: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ are Riemann integrable and $f(x) = g(x)$ except on the middle-thirds Cantor set $C$. Prove that $f$ and $g$ have the same integral. Is the same true if $f(x)=g(x)$ except for $x$ in the rationals?

Any hint or help with this question please. Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you know measure theory?

Comment: No, I am not in measure theory. I am in advanced calculus, so our measure theory is limited. We only talked about zero sets.

Comment: Go through my answer. That's all I have on the problem. Let me know if it doesn't help. I'll delete it.

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi Thank you, that helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have studied measure theory, you'd know that if $f(x)=g(x)$ almost everywhere (i.e. $f(x)\ne g(x)$ on a set of measure $0$). Then $f$ and $g$ would have same integral.

**Note**: The measure of Cantor Ternary Set is $0$, the same is the case with $\mathbb{Q}$